# Custom Object Multiple Page Layout

Tags: apex, custom-object, workflow, page-layout

I have a Custom Object called "Property".  As new records are built, I would like my sales people to go stages when they change the Status pick list of the property.  Is it possible for the user to switch from different layout when a pick list is selected.

For example, if I change the picklist status to "known", when saved it goes to a different Property page layout.  I call that page layout "Stage 2" then when they change the status again it changes to "Stage 3" layout.

Is this possible?  Can you help on code, work flow or just guidance would be great.

Appreciate in advance

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control which page layouts are displayed by a combination of recordTypes and Profiles. You can go your custom object page, scroll down to the page layout section and you will find a `Page layout assignment` button which will help you assign the page layouts.

To address your problem, you would need as many number of record types as the number of stages you have. Once all the recordTypes are created, you have to create a workflow rule which updates the recordType as and when there's a change in the Picklist value. On a side note, you can also control the picklist value based on the recordType. Once this is done, create different page-layout for each recordTypes and this assign the page layouts as you wish.

Comment: This worked well.  I appreciate it so much.  i did the first 4 and will work on the rest but it work so well.